# python - different encoding results by setting the "encoding" parameter in diff. functions

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

I have a function like

```
f = open('workfile', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
df = pandas.read_csv(...)
```

, which opens a csv file. When I tried to set the `encoding` parameter to `read_csv` function, I got other encoding results, than by setting the parameter to `open()` function: for example the **€** and **ö** characters were misinterpreted by setting the parameter to `read_csv` function. Can anyone explain me, why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens in your program

```
f = open('workfile', 'r', encoding='utf-8') # 1
df = pandas.read_csv(f, encoding=e) # 2
```

(1) The file is told to decode bytes using the encoding 'utf-8'. If you print the representation of the file handle f it will show something like

```
 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
```

When you pull text from this wrapper you will get a unicode string.

(2) read_csv() is told to use some encoding e. Therefore it will convert the unicode string to bytes (doing an implicit encode() -- which will use 'utf-8' on my system) which then are decoded with the decoding e.

Here is a little test program for illustration

```
import pandas

for file in ['workfile-utf-8.csv', 'workfile-cp1252.csv']:
    for file_encoding in ['utf-8', 'cp1252']:
        for pandas_encoding in [None, 'utf-8', 'cp1252']:
            with open(file, 'r', encoding=file_encoding) as fp:
                try:
                    print('***', file, fp, pandas_encoding)
                    df = pandas.read_csv(fp, encoding=pandas_encoding)
                    print(df)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
```

The files mentioned are in an encoding that is reflected in their name.

The output should be like this (may depend on your environment)

```
(1) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='utf-8'> None
       a          b        c
0      Hällo       €uro       Öl
(2) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='utf-8'> utf-8
       a          b        c
0      Hällo       €uro       Öl
(3) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='utf-8'> cp1252
        a            b         c
0      HÃ¤llo       â‚¬uro       Ã–l
(4) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='cp1252'> None
        a            b         c
0      HÃ¤llo       â‚¬uro       Ã–l
(5) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='cp1252'> utf-8
        a            b         c
0      HÃ¤llo       â‚¬uro       Ã–l
(6) workfile-utf-8.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-utf-8.csv' mode='r'
encoding='cp1252'> cp1252
          a                b            c
0      HÃƒÂ¤llo       Ã¢â€šÂ¬uro       Ãƒâ€“l
(7) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='utf-8'> None
Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
(8) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='utf-8'> utf-8
Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
(9) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='utf-8'> cp1252
Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
(10) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> None
       a          b        c
0      Hällo       €uro       Öl
(11) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> utf-8
       a          b        c
0      Hällo       €uro       Öl
(12) workfile-cp1252.csv <_io.TextIOWrapper name='workfile-cp1252.csv'
mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> cp1252
        a            b         c
0      HÃ¤llo       â‚¬uro       Ã–l
```

(1) File is utf-8 -> decode utf-8 -> use as is -> ok

(2) File is utf-8 -> decode utf-8 -> (encode w. default) -> (decode utf-8) -> ok here, but not in other environments

(3) File is utf-8 -> decode utf-8 -> (encode w. default) -> (decode cp1252) -> turns Hällo into HÃ¤llo, etc.

...

(7) File is cp1252 -> decode utf-8 -> raises UnicodeDecodeError, and leads to an error

...

(11) File is cp1252 -> decode cp1252 -> (encode w. default) -> (decode utf-8) -> ok here, but not in other environments

...

Interesting (and funny to look at) is in particular case (6) turning Hällo,€uro, Öl into HÃƒÂ¤llo,Ã¢â€šÂ¬uro,Ãƒâ€“l

It corresponds to a sequence:

```
>>> x1 = 'Hällo,€uro, Öl'
>>> x1
'Hällo,€uro, Öl'
>>> x2 = x1.encode()
>>> x2
b'H\xc3\xa4llo,\xe2\x82\xacuro, \xc3\x96l'
>>> x3 = x2.decode('cp1252')
>>> x3
'HÃ¤llo,â‚¬uro, Ã–l'
>>> x4 = x3.encode()
>>> x4
b'H\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4llo,\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xacuro, \xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x93l'
>>> x5 = x4.decode('cp1252')
>>> x5
'HÃƒÂ¤llo,Ã¢â€šÂ¬uro, Ãƒâ€“l'
```